# Relation between altitudes and three angles and their sides.

Tags: geometry, number-theory, trigonometry, pi, plane-geometry

For a triangle of $\angle A B C$ the sides of  $ a,b,c$ are written in a way of $a=\frac{\sin A}{\sin C}$, $b=\frac{\sin B}{\sin C}$, $c=\frac{\sin C}{\sin C}$ and the heights $h_a,h_b,h_c$ are written in a form $\frac {h_c}{h_a}=$,$\frac{h_c}{h_b}=$,$\frac{h_c}{h_c}$ to give us $ a$ and $b$. and the base $c=1$.

If I have a triangle with sides $5,5,4 $ and their altitudes are $\sqrt {21},\sqrt {13.44},\sqrt {13.44}$ , why do they simplify to give us a special kind of triangle where $a=1.25,b=1.25,c=1$

> $\sqrt\frac {21}{13.44}=1.25$

Angles 
$3=0.16+0.16+0.68^2+0.84+0.84+(1-0.68^2)$

Laws of Cosine ,when we have all $3$ lengths are:

> $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(A)$
>
> $b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac\cos(B)$
>
> $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(C)$

Here we have sides $1.25,1.25 and 1$,a simplest version of the triangle measuring $5,5,4$.

And for three sides of a triangle $a,b,c$,and $\angle ABC$. The legs of the heights $h_a,h_b,h_c$ are situated on three sides of the triangle.
For one side $a$ I have $\frac{b-\cos(A)}{\cos(C)}=a$ and for the second side $b$ I have $\frac{a-\cos(B)}{\cos(C)}=b$ and the third side which is $c$ as the base of the triangle equals to $1$.

> $\sqrt{\sin^2(B)+(a-\cos(B))^2}=b$
>
> $\sqrt{\sin^2(A)+(b-\cos(A))^2}=a$
>
> $\sqrt{\sin^2(A)+(\cos(A))^2}=c$
>
> by using consecutive or non consecutive numbers:
>   $a<b<c $ we're able to define $\theta$ without conversion
>
> $\frac{a}{c}=\cos(C)$    $(1-\frac{a}{c})\times\sqrt\frac{(a+c)}{(c-a)}=\sin(C)$
>
> $\sqrt\frac{(c-b)}{c}=\cos(B)$   $\sqrt\frac{b}{c}=\sin(B)$

Find

> $\cos(A)$  &   $\sin(A)$ which we already know.
>
> Question is: why $\frac{h_c}{h_b}$; $\frac{h_c}{h_a}$;$\frac{h_c}{h_c}$ and. $\frac{\sin A}{\sin C}$; $\frac{\sin B}{\sin C}$ $\frac{\sin C}{\sin C}$equal to the sides $a,b,c$?

[image]

Comment: Not entirely clear what the question is, but it may help that $\,a \cdot h_a = b \cdot h_b = c \cdot h_c = 2S\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I have added a drawing.

Comment: `Question is: why three altitudes and three angles give. the >result of the sides .?` Still not clear on what this question is supposed to mean.

Comment: @dxiv what is the relation of the three altitudes and three angles and three sides?

Comment: ***Which*** relations? There are many of them, see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)), [2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Altitude.html), [3](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa2013/Hendricks/Writeup8/Writeup8.html) for example. If you have a question about some *particular* relation, then ask *that* question, and make it plenty clear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: @dxiv thanks, I'll do my best!